# Sharing Google's OAuth authorizations from Marketplace Add-on to an external application

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

I've created a Google Workspace Marketplace add-on for Calendar, more specifically a conference add-on for event creation (like Zoom). This add-on authorizes with the Google account of the user, for the scopes determined in the manifest.

Question: is there a way how I can use this authorization in other parts of my application? This application is external and does not live in Google ecosystem. E.g. sharing access/refresh tokens? But they expire and I don't know which API credentials are used, when authorization happened via the manifest from an add-on instead of build from scratch OAuth integration.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use it precisely for the scopes defined in the manifest. Explicitly request the user to grant permission for further scopes if necessary. Not doing so would not only not work but also dishonest towards them

Comment: Refresh tokens should not be expiring.  If you are sharing them around to different parts of your system this may effect the verification process your going to have to tell google what you are doing with the data.   Each app should have its own project on google cloud console and its own client id and client secret

Comment: @DaImTo, thanks for thinking along. I think I can't retrieve the refresh token from within the app script (only access token, which expires rather quickly) and easily share it with my external application. I also believe this refresh token is tied to the OAuth client-id of the add-on, and I can't refresh it with other client-ids.